# Nagios doesn't get exports from /etc/profile

Tags: export, environment-variables, nagios, env

I've got Nagios and Oracle sqlplus client installed on my server. Sqlplus needs few environment variables for its run, so I added exports to `/etc/profile`.
Login as root sets variables right, login as user nagios sets is also OK but when I run some checks from nagios web interface (these checks are written in bash), they end with an error `Error: Empty result from sqlplus. Check plugin settings and Oracle status.` 
When I run these checks from terminal as root or as nagios user, everything is OK, that's how I found out that problem is in env variables.

I will be glad for any suggestions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found that is a bug from nagios, you can check documentation from [this link](http://bugzilla.globus.org/globus/show_bug.cgi?id=6539).

You will find in file `/etc/init.d/nagios` this code.

```
# Load any extra environment variables for Nagios and its plugins
if test -f /etc/sysconfig/nagios; then
       . /etc/sysconfig/nagios
fi
```

Just create the file `nagios` on the `/etc/sysconfig/` path for Fedora or rhel with the extra variables that you need.
on case.

```
[root@server sysconfig]# cat nagios 
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
```

and that's it.

Best regard Marco.

Comment: That bug url is dead now, but this one seems to work: https://bugzilla.mcs.anl.gov/globus/show_bug.cgi?id=6539

Comment: I tried this with icinga2 but it's not working. Has anyone a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

It is the same issue with the NRPE as Marco mentionned before.

you have to add the environement variables into /etc/sysconfig/nrpe then you have to restart nrpe : service nrpe restart

Thanks
Youssef